# how to add keydown event in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, text, autocomplete, keydown

scenario :
 I have text field for search city,where I've implemented auto complete functionality.
Now what I want whenever I try to get select city using down key (keyboard), it should select city visiting list. 
May anyone give me some suggestion, how can I do this.

Still facing problem. Please check link below.

http://hotels.travelbookers.co/

try to search like :  mu

Looking for your help.

Regards,
Sandeep Thakur

Comment: try google jquery keydown event

Comment: yep, you need to google things before asking.

Comment: Still facing probem . Please check link below.  http://hotels.travelbookers.co/

Answer (score 0):

You can refer:

http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

```
$( "#target" ).keydown(function() {
alert( "Handler for .keydown() called." );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkKey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;
    if(e.keyCode=='40'){
        alert(e.keyCode+': DownArrow');
    }
}

var inp = document.getElementById('input');
inp.onkeydown = checkKey;
```

jQuery:

```
$('#input').keydown(function(e){

    e = e || window.event;
    if(e.keyCode=='40'){
        alert(e.keyCode+': DownArrow');
    }
});
```

arrow keys are triggered by **[onkeydown](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp)**.

keycodes are:

- left = 37
- up = 38
- right = 39
- down = 40